# Is it possible to hide partitions from windows installation?

Tags: windows, windows-7, partitioning, gparted, easeus-partition-manager

Is it possible to hide partitions from windows installation?

In the old days, the 1990s, there was partition magic that had an option to hide partitions.

GParted has an option to hide a partition, but Windows 7 installation still sees it.

Easeus and Partition Wizard don't seem to have an option I can see to hide a partition

I'm using Windows 7 but I think this should apply for later versions of Windows too.

These are my partitions..  Disk Management shows both disk0 and disk1 as having partition format of MBR.

[image]

Comment: "In the old days…" – Does it count as retrocomputing? Even if not, see [this](https://retrocomputing.stackexchange.com/q/16685).

Comment: @KamilMaciorowski thanks.. looks like maybe current tools have decided there's no point then (and gparted isn't doing it right, especially not on MBR)

Answer (score 1):

Current partition editors "hide" partitions by deleting their drive-letter,
which I suppose isn't enough for you.

The only solution I can think of is to encrypt the disk/partition with
[VeraCrypt](https://www.veracrypt.fr/code/VeraCrypt/about/)
using whole-partition encryption.

You might also use the stronger feature of
[Hidden Volume](https://veracrypt.eu/en/docs/hidden-volume/)
where a VeraCrypt volume is hidden within another VeraCrypt volume.

For more information see
[Full Disk Encryption with VeraCrypt](https://medium.com/@securitystreak/veracrypt-full-disk-drive-encryption-fde-157eacbf0b61)
(and the included warnings).

Comment: you might be over generalising a bit about current partition editors.. GParted apparently does something (not deleting drive letter) https://retrocomputing.stackexchange.com/q/16685     (though very ineffective at least for MBR).    And the other programs I mentioned don't have a hide option at all.  The Veracrypt idea sounds like it should work!

Comment: veracrypt seems to be a bit tricky for me to use, says "veracrypt system encryption pretest failed" so I can't test this.